# How do I retrieve Image with Firebase in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'd like to retrieve image I already did saved with Firebase in iOS.
I tried to save image url and retrieve url but I can't see image in my application.

this is my code

```
    listRef.observeEventType(.Value) { (snapshot) in
        self.textcontent = snapshot.value as? String
    }
    //print nil 
    print("textcontent is \(self.textcontent)")


    if let url = NSURL(string: self.textcontent!) {
        if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
            image.image = UIImage(data: data)
        }
```

How do I get there?

Comment: Is it entering the data if let ? Put some more break points in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a tad unclear what you are asking as Firebase stores strings and not images. However, they can be encoded as a string for storage if you actually want to store the image (10M limit per node)

It appears you are trying to get a string from Firebase, convert to NSURL which is from another service and retrieve that data from the other service.

Your code isn't going to work consistently if at all. Firebase is asynchronous in nature and the code needs to wait for firebase to return it's data before working with it.

So here's a solution; note that once the block returns with the data, you can process it *within the block*

```
listRef.observeEventType(.Value) { (snapshot) in
        self.textcontent = snapshot.value as? String

        print("textcontent is \(self.textcontent)")

        if let url = NSURL(string: self.textcontent!) {
          if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
              image.image = UIImage(data: data)
          }
        }
    }
```

You should probably add some error checking as well.

Oh, and I don't know what your use case is, but this code attaches an observer to the listRef node so if that data changes, this code will be called each time a change occurs. You may want to use observeSingleEventOfType instead.